# PHP-Yii: Using Yiis logger when a request is not completed due to php level error

Tags: php, logging, yii

This is probably a yii specific question, even though I wouldn't surprised if experienced non-Yii we developers will be also able to contribute.

I often encounter the following situation:

1. My application fails due to a *fatal* error on the php level. Something like $var->property when $var==null
2. I want to understand how $var came to be ==null.
3. I'd use logs for this, however, problem is that no logs are left when a request is ended due to php error.

edit: this only happens for *fatal* errors. For other php errors I have my logs back

An example:
For

```
$nonExistingVar->someProperty;
```

I do have my logs recorded, as it yields PHP Error Undefined variable: nonExistingVar
However, if I do define the variable and set it to null,

```
$tmp = null;
$tmp->prop;
```

Then I loose the logs, as it results in "**Fatal** error: Call to a member function hasErrors() on a non-object"

Does anybody understand why does it happen? And how can the logger be anyway used in this situations? I tried setting autoFlush=1, doesn't help

Thanks

Gidi

Comment: You should probably post some code.

Comment: Give a concrete example of an error that doesn't get logged.

Comment: It's not that some error doesn't get log, no logs at all are recorded (lot of trace logs) due to the request being terminated abruptly by a fatal error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below allowed me to have my logs even on fatal errors:

```
function yiiCorrectShutdown()
{
    Yii::app()->end();

    //the following line will work as well
    //Yii::app()->log->processLogs(null);
}

register_shutdown_function('yiiCorrectShutdown');
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an extension class that logs in real-time thus avoiding any need to modify flow paths. I posted it here on the [Yii Wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/140/real-time-logging/)